# efficiently getting all my trades from binance api

Tags: binance

I want to download all my trades from Binance using the api.  The problem I have is that the `api/v3/myTrades` api call requires a market symbol. As there are hundreds of market symbols, I need to make hundreds of API calls to ensure that I cover all possibilities.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?  Either another API call that doesn't require a market symbol, or a way to get the symbols that I have traded in?

Comment: What do you mean with “cover all possibilities “, do you really trade in hundreds of different symbols every day and don’t you know which ones you have traded in? Also, have you looked into using a user data stream?

Comment: I have not looked at the user data stream. Does it cover historical data?

Comment: Have you found an approach? I'm having the exact same question right now.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it.  Have asked the exchange to add it as a feature but they're unresponsive.

Comment: Have you found any solutions?

Comment: Not really.  My approach is to "intelligently" query the various endpoints in order (most likely to have trades first).  Essentially, you need to keep your own records of what orders have been placed and use that data to query the API in an efficient manner.

Comment: If they could make a request that gives only the name of the pairs that user has traded, it would fix most of my problem...

Comment: Do you have an example of this approach for a single symbol ? It would be most useful thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://explorer.bitquery.io to get historical info, though this isn't *precisely* what you're asking for, since it's a different API.